# How vibrate upto 30 seconds iOS device in background while receiving push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented APNS for push notification. I am using custom sound for alert notification that will play 30 seconds siren audio file. that is working. while playing that sound I get only one time of vibration with the duration of 2 secs. I need the vibration upto 30 seconds . how can I achieve that.
this is the payload I am using.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"alert message","badge":1,"sound":"SIREN.caf"}}
```

I have tried implementing code for vibrating upto 30 seconds. it will be call on

> didReceiveRemoteNotification

```
    -(void)vibrateDevice{
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, ^{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
  });
  vibrateCount++;
  if (vibrateCount<30) {
    //        [self performSelector:@selector(vibrateDevice) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(vibrateDevice) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
  }
}
```

> the problem is I can able to vibrate only in app foreground. when app
>   is killed or in background vibration code part is not working.

Comment: when an application is not in the foreground then push notification can not awake application for execution code.

Comment: thanks llesh, is any other possible ways available to achieve vibrating a device upto 30 secs when receiving push notifications

Comment: Try writing the vibrateDevice method in Service Extension, and call it on notification receive.